# How to encrypt files in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

I have files which I want to encrypt and store in RTC source control. Do the files need to be encrypted using an external program or does RTC / RTC source control support encrypting files within the stream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/71793/encryption-mechanism-used-for-storing-source-code-in-repos) summarizes the current situation regarding file encryption in RTC:

> You would need to raise an enhancement request if you wanted this handled by RTC.
>
> There are some other options that might help.
>
> - The underlying database should have security mechanisms to encrypt data - it is worth looking at that.
> - Next, you could also encrypt the disk the data is stored on (for example, I have worked with a customer that used BitLocker - part of Windows Server - to encrypt the disk RTC and the database runs on).
>
> It is worth asking more questions about the request. For example - who are they trying to conceal the source code from?

So using an external program for file encryption would still be required with the current versions of RTC (4.x).